# Searching for text within a word document

Tags: c#, text-search, microsoft-word

I hope someone can help me with this.  I have been searching for days trying to find a way to extract some text from a word document and update the document with some other text.  This is not your standard search and replace functionality.  This is what I mean.  I have a word document that can have 1 to many occurrences of this: lat=29.78908972, long=-82.03912832.  I need to start at the beginning of the document and extract the lat and lon values, pass those values to a Google service that will return the county associated with that lat/lon.  I then need to update the document with the county.  Repeat this until the end of the document.  I also need to keep the word formatting.  Everything I have found is seems to be of the search and replace variety, meaning, find this text and replace it with this text.  I have also explored using bookmarks but because the lat/lon values are in a loop (in the document build), it only updated the last bookmark, not each bookmark.  I guess because they were named the same?  The document is actually a template that gets filled in from a third party app we are using called DeviceMagic.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your Word file is in .docx format, and if the lat/lon values are in a format that can be reliably matched by a regular expression, then you could build a processing pipeline something like this:

1. Use zip (or 7zip) to extract the XML file of the document text from the .docx file.
2. Use *grep* to extract all unique lat/lon specifications to a text file, one per line.
3. Write a bit of code in Python or the language of your choice to read the coordinates reverse-geocode them, and write out the results in the form of a *sed* script of text replacement commands that will replace each lat/lon specification with the corresponding county name.
4. Use *sed* to run the sed script on the XML file of document text.
5. Update the .docx archive with the modified XML file.

You could replace the use of *grep* and *sed* with all custom code if you prefer, though using existing tools like these will probably be simpler.